# SSLException during creation of new project in SoapUI using API Blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

I am attempting to use the API Blueprint plug-in for SoapUI.  I have tried SoapUI version 5.1.0, 5.1.2 and Ready! API 1.2.2, all with the same result (others in my organization are experiencing the same issue).

When I attempt to create a new project of type "API Blueprint Definition (REST)", during the import phase, I get the following error (full stack trace at end of message):

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
```

I see there is a call made to https://api.apiblueprint.org:443 during this phase, but it seems the operation is successful.

I have tried adding some properties to the .vmoptions file as I have seen suggested in some other posts, but they did not help:

```
 -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
 -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false
 -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

I am at a loss to explain what is happening since the log is not particularly helpful.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Ian W

```
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.write(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:73)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.writeTo(StringEntity.java:170)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:231)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.smartbear.soapui.blueprint.BlueprintImporter.convertBlueprintToAST(BlueprintImporter.groovy:116)
    at com.smartbear.soapui.blueprint.BlueprintImporter$convertBlueprintToAST.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.smartbear.soapui.blueprint.BlueprintImporter.importBlueprint(BlueprintImporter.groovy:62)
    at com.smartbear.soapui.blueprint.actions.BlueprintImporterWorker.construct(BlueprintImporterWorker.java:53)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What Java version do you use?

Comment: I have JRE 8.0.45, but it looks like Ready! API uses an embedded JRE, version 1.7.0_72-b14.  I tried overlaying my JRE folder into Ready! API and even though it now recognizing the new version, I still get the same SSL internal exception.

Comment: There was an issue with Apiary's backend conversion logic.  They have corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`api.apiblueprint.org` seems to require SNI support, so you should try the opposite:

`-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`

SNI should be supported by Java 7+, therefore Java 6 might be unsupported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that does not resolve the problem.  I am using Java 8.  Also, I have moved on to trying to import the sample "Simplest API.md" with the same result.

Comment: @IanWilliamson SSL configuration on the apiblueprint API has been changed, does the problem persist?